# Usb tethering not working in 16.04 LTS after reconnecting phone

Tags: networking, usb, android, tethering

Usb tethering from Android phone works fine when connecting phone for the first time after boot, but does not work after disconnecting end reconnecting the phone. Connection information and ifconfig results are same before and after reconnecting. I can even ping Primary DNS address of the phone after reconnecting but cant ping or browse any web server.

Comment: In case someone stumbles upon this question - I was getting same behavior on debian buster, disabling openvpn.service fixed it for me.